# Cannot install Simple OData Client in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, odata, nuget-package

This suggested Nuget Client will not install on Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. When I attempt to install, I receive the following error message:

"Could not install package 'Microsoft.OData.Edm 6.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

The link to this Nuget package is https://components.xamarin.com/view/simple.odata.client.

When trying to install other Nuget packages I receive a similar error message naming a different package as the error source.

Comment: What are you doing with OData on the client side? OData is typically used on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing a couple of things. The `Simple.OData.Client` package is not the `Microsoft.OData.Edm` package. Also you say you link to a NuGet package, put you link to the Xamarin Component Store.

Furthermore, I think you should [read up on](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) what PCLs are and how to use them. When I look at the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Edm/) for the `Microsoft.OData.Edm` package I see that it does not support iOS and Android. So, you will never be able to install it to a PCL which targets one of these platforms. You should, however, be able to install the `Simple.OData.Client` package according to the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client/).

PCLs have a certain profile. When you right-click and go to the properties of a PCL library, you can check all platforms that you want it to support. Each combination of platforms have a certain profile, specified by a three digit number, like 111 or 259. The parts of the .NET framework that are available to you, are an intersection of the functionalities that are available on *all* targeted platforms. If a functionality is supported by iOS but not on Android, it's not supported in your PCL.

This is also why NuGets need to support the specific profile that you are targeting, because it can only use the methods that are available in it.